# RegEx return substring from matched string

Tags: regex

I'm pretty unfamiliar with regex. I would like to run a regex search against lines like:

```
if env == production
    #define DBHOST "serv1.ns.com"
    #define DBSLAVEHOST "serv2.ns.com"
    #define DBHOSTAUX "serv3.ns.com"
endif
```

I have the following which finds the lines I want: `^(?=.*\\bDB)(?=.*HOST).*`, but I'm not positive how to match and return whatever the last word in the line is -- i.e., `serv1.ns.com`, `serv2.ns.com`, `serv3.ns.com`

Comment: will the desired output be in double quotes in all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\s*#define\s+[A-Z]*DB[A-Z]*HOST[A-Z]*\s+"?(.*?)"?$
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/tI5aG0/3)

Comment: Thanks - I want to make sure it contains both `DB` and `HOST` though.. so this is *almost* what I want right?

Comment: Does this actually return the result `serv1.ns.com`, etc.? Which part of your regex is the `value` portion?

Comment: @MrDuk the first capturing group is the `value`, you can see it on the sample site on the right